# Unable to create a case in salesforce using API

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

Hi I am trying to create a case in salesforce using soap API I am not able to create it as salesfroce API keeps erroring out with error message.

We can't save this record because the “Send Email to Contact on Case Creation” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details.
CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER

I have tried seeing if there is a workflow assosiated with it or the docs which shows me the error code CANNOT_EXECUTE_FLOW_TRIGGER.

Comment: Check Setup -> Process Builder, not just Setup -> Flows.